# Appending arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, append

Is it possible to concatenate two or more arraylist ? I have following case:

```
 private Arraylist<Double> getContextVectorsize(int sizeContext){
     ArrayList<Double> contextList = new ArrayList<Double>();
     for(int i =0 ; i< sizeContext; i++){
         contextList = //TODO 
     }   
}
```

I would like to append all the arraylist in order and want to generate an arraylist of 
 `size = sizeContext*ArraylistOfSingleMember`

Comment: How come the Javadoc of `ArrayList` or even that of `List` did not allow you to answer this question yourself?

Comment: Your sample code and your question do not match.

Comment: Which arraylists do you want to concatenate?

Comment: I would like to append a number of Arraylist<Double> to generate arraylist<Double> of all.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the addAll() method.

Comment: addAll() takes argument boolean, my argument is Arraylist<Double>.

Answer (score 2):

Use list1.addAll(list2), this returns true if it worked AND updates list1. Here is a full code example from tutorialspoint.com.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {

   // create an empty array list1 with an initial capacity
   ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

   // use add() method to add elements in the list
   arrlist.add(12);
   arrlist.add(20);
   arrlist.add(45);

   // let us print all the elements available in list1
   System.out.println("Printing list1:");
   for (Integer number : arrlist) {
   System.out.println("Number = " + number);
   }

   // create an empty array list2 with an initial capacity
   ArrayList<Integer> arrlist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

   // use add() method to add elements in list2
   arrlist2.add(25);
   arrlist2.add(30);
   arrlist2.add(31);
   arrlist2.add(35);

   // let us print all the elements available in list2
   System.out.println("Printing list2:");
   for (Integer number : arrlist2) {
   System.out.println("Number = " + number);
   }

   // inserting all elements, list2 will get printed after list1
   arrlist.addAll(arrlist2);

   System.out.println("Printing all the elements");
   // let us print all the elements available in list1
   for (Integer number : arrlist) {
   System.out.println("Number = " + number);
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =0 ; i< sizeContext; i++){
    contextList.addAll( an instance of ArrayList<Double>);
}
```